# How to use multiple buddypress mobile themes

Tags: wordpress, mobile, wordpress-theming, buddypress

How can I use multiple themes for buddypress mobile, I want to switch quickly between those themes. This is for the purpose of creating styles and testing theme. Also comparing those themes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `/wp-content/sunrise.php`. There you can write smth like this:

```
add_filter('option_template', 'filter_get_option');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'filter_get_option');
function filter_get_option($value){
    // here you can based on url or any other thing 
    // change the theme on a fly, like this:
    if(true){
        $value = 'theme_1';
    }else{
        $value = 'theme_2';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

This is rather like a hack, but it works. `theme_1` and `theme_1` are themes folders (those inside `/wp-content/themes/`